# Django exception handler for the default-brench in try-except block

Tags: django

Basically, my goal is best descriped by example:

View

```
define test_view()
   try
        # some code block
   except error_type_1:
        status = 428
        # do something
   except error_type_2:
        # do something else
   except # any other mistake
        # print the error to console
   finally 
        return smth
```

My question is, is there any default-block in python try-except so that I can grab the custom error message that Django print to the console if know exception is present in the view ? As far as I understand, `else` block is not intended for this. The rationale behind this question is that after I surround my code with try-except block, it becomes hard to understand what is going on in the code in those cases where the error rose not as a result of what I anticipated.

Comment: It sounds like you're using a try block around an entire section of code rather than using it to catch specific errors.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is it bad practice ?

Comment: I suppose thats opinion based. I would say so for the very reason you've even asked this question, you're making your code unnecessarily long. Rather than focusing on the programs intended flow, you're butchering it to force it to work

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I will read about further. Now my major problem is that something is wrong with my syntax. But because my code is surrounded by try-block, the app is finished successfully, and no error is rendered in the console

Comment: Could you just provide a code snippet for fetching the error message. As for your initial comment, I will take this into account and improve the code later

Comment: The [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) has an ok example (as well as a warning stating this is a bad idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a `return` statement in the `finally` block, you're effectively hiding the error. Usually any uncaught exception is reraised after the `finally` block, but the `return` statement returns control from the function before this can happen. It's better to move the return statement out of the `finally` block and let the unexpected error propagate naturally:

```
def test_view():
    try
        # some code block
    except error_type_1:
        status = 428
        # do something
    except error_type_2:
        # do something else

    return smth
```

You can catch all exceptions with a bare except clause or by catching `Exception`, though this is often not recommended, as it can easily hide the details needed to debug the problem:

```
try:
    do_something()
except:
    handle_exception()

try:
    do_something()
except Exception as exc:
    handle_exception(exc)
```

When a view function raises an exception, Django will do this for you and give you a detailed error page, which includes the error message, traceback, local variables and more.